# How to use a loop to check if hyphens are in correct place for a phone number

Tags: formatting

I want to use a loop to step through each character of a string, checking for a digit or hyphen in the appropriate spots. For example, how would I check a phone number format like 604-000-0000?? Thanks.

Comment: What language you are using & what you have tried..

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code to loop through a string to validate hyphen locations for a phone number of format 000-000-0000

```
for(i = 0; i < length of string; i++)
{
    if((i is 3 or i is 7) and character at location i is a not hyphen)
    {
       print("non hyphen found at location " + i);
    }
    if((i is not 3 and i is not 7) and character at location i is not a digit)
    {
       print("non digit found at location " + i);
    }

}
```

However this is almost certainly not the best way to validate a phone number.  You should be either using an existing phone number validation method, or just write a simple Regular Expression.